# ASP.NET CORE REST API (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: c#, .net, api, iis, http-status-code-401

---

I'm getting troubles with the publishing of my REST API made in ASP.NET CORE.

When I'm debugging my code in the localhost, it's all right.

But when I want to publish it in IIS 10.0, I can navigate into the swagger UI.

Nevertheless, if I want to use a Get method that allows anonymous authorization, I get 401 error.

Please help this poor and junior soul.
If you need some more information, please ask me

Comment: Add your startup.cs configuration block code of Swagger UI then put into question.

Comment: Which authorization scheme are you using in your application?

Comment: Could you please post the details error message about the 401 error and its sub code? You could find it in the IIS logs or asp.net core's stdoutLogFile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JwtBearer and this is my startup.cs code:

---

```
 public class Startup
{
    private readonly string _myPolicy = "_myPolicy";
    public  Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;

        });



        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
               //My secret parameters
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_myPolicy)));

        services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
        {
            config.SwaggerDoc("V1", new Info
            {
                Title = "MiApi",
                Version = "V1",

            });
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        ConfigurationService(services);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(config =>
        {
            config.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/V1/swagger.json", "MiApiV1");
            config.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
        });
        app.Use(next => async context => {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }

            catch
            {
                // If the headers have already been sent, you can't replace the status code.
                // In this case, throw an exception to close the connection.
                if (context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller-home}/{action = Index}/{id?}");
        });


        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

---

Besides, if you have a piece of advice to me about my code, it's welcome.